# Python async CancelledError() with no details

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

The following code fails and I'm not able to get the actual error, I just get numerous CancelledError messages

```
import aiobotocore, asyncio

async def replicate_to_region(chunks, region):
    session = aiobotocore.get_session()
    client = session.create_client('dynamodb', region_name=region)
    start = 0
    while True:
        chunk = chunks[start]
        item = {'my_table': chunk}
        response = await client.batch_write_item(RequestItems=item)

async def main():
    asyncio.gather(*(replicate_to_region(payloads, region) for region in regions))

asyncio.run(main())
```

I get the following errors;

```
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f6fb65a34a8>
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f6fb64c82b0>
_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=CancelledError()>
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=CancelledError()>
```

I've tried quite a number of variations of the `replicate_to_region` function but they all fail with the same error above. It would be useful just to be able to see what the actual error is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
async def main():
    asyncio.gather(...)
```

[asyncio.gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) is an awaitable itself:

> **awaitable** asyncio.gather(*aws, loop=None, return_exceptions=False)

It means you should use await when deal with it:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*(replicate_to_region(payloads, region) for region in regions))
```

---

off-topic:

I didn't work with `aiobotocore` and not sure if it's important, but it's better to do as documentation says. In particular you should probably use `async with` when creating a client [as example shows](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore#basic-example).

Comment: This was the issue. I found it myself after starting again from scratch. Thanks!